# Is CA1001: TypesThatOwnDisposableFieldsShouldBeDisposable Valid?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, ca1001

If I have the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        var someTypeWithAnEvent = new SomeTypeWithAnEvent();        

        using (var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            someTypeWithAnEvent.Begun += (sender, e) => signal.Set();
            someTypeWithAnEvent.Begin();
            signal.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

FxCop seems to throw a [CA1001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172(VS.80).aspx) error:

> CA1001 : Microsoft.Design : Implement
>   IDisposable on 'Foo'
>   because it creates members of the
>   following IDisposable types:
>   'ManualResetEvent'.

This doesn't seem valid in this instance because I'm disposing of the `ManualResetEvent` through the `using` block.

Am I missing something here or is there an error in the rule?

Comment: I've now updated the example to give a bit more context around where the code is within the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a false warning indeed. What version of FxCop are you using? It is reportedly a [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/b7d30207-2dd3-4e0f-9061-eb16de0e1c57) but might be solved now.

Comment: It's the version that comes with Visual Studio 2008 (version 9.0.30729.1 SP).  As far as I know I've not installed FxCop seperately.

Comment: I'm getting this with the same ManualResetEvent in VS2013 (this thread has been dead for a while but just wanted to make it known that it still happens)

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess: you're accessing signal in a lambda expression and the '..' in the error message is a compiler generated class. In this case it's safe to suppress the message.

Comment: Half right yeah.  It *is* being set within a lambda, but the type referred to in error message isn't a compiler generated class, it's the type for the enclosing method.

Comment: I've updated the original question with a bit more context regarding where the code is.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/b7d30207-2dd3-4e0f-9061-eb16de0e1c57) it's a known bug and therefore it should be save to ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. This makes no sense - the signal will not survive undisposed. Looks to me like an error in the parser (for the condition). I would document it and put a pgragma into the file to supporess it.